# Create label column in dataframe according to an existing date column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and struggling with the fact that functions are able to operate on whole vectors without having to explicitly specify this.

#### My goal

I have a data frame `calls` with multiple columns, one of which is a “date” column. Now I want to add a new column, “daytime”, that labels the daytime the particular entry’s date falls into:

```
> calls
     call_id length             date    direction       daytime
1        258    531    1400594572974     outgoing     afternoon
2        259      0    1375555528144   unanswered       evening
3        260    778    1385922648396     incoming       evening
```

#### What I have done so far

I have already implemented methods that return a vector of booleans like that:

```
# Operates on POSIXlt timestamps
is.earlymorning <- function(date) {
  hour(floor_date(date, "hour")) >= 5 & hour(floor_date(date, "hour")) < 9
}
```

The call `is.earlymorning(“2014-05-20 16:02:52”, “2013-08-03 20:45:28”, “2013-12-01 19:30:48”)` would thus return (“FALSE”, “FALSE”, “FALSE”). What I am currently struggling with is to implement a function that actually returns labels. What I would like the function to do is the following:

```
# rawDate is a long value of the date as ms since 1970
Daytime <- function(rawDate) {
  date <- as.POSIXlt(as.numeric(rawDate) / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01")

  if (is.earlymorning(date)) {
    "earlymorning"
  } else if (is.morning(date)) {
    "morning"
  } else if (is.afternoon(date)) {
    "afternoon"
  } else if (is.evening(date)) {
    "evening"
  } else if (is.earlynight(date)) {
    "earlynight"
  } else if (is.latenight(date)) {
    "latenight"
  }
}
```

#### The problem

Obviously, my above approach does not work since the if-conditions would operate on whole vectors in my example. Is there an elegant way to solve this problem? I am sure I am confusing or missing some important points, but as I mentioned I am pretty new to R.

In short, what I want to implement is a function that returns a vector of labels according to a vector of date values:

```
# Insert new column with daytime labels
calls$daytime <- Daytime(df$date)
# or something like that:
calls$daytime <- sapply(df$date, Daytime)

# Daytime(1400594572974, 1375555528144, 1385922648396) => (“afternoon”, “evening”, “evening”)
```

Comment: Look at `ifelse` for a vectorized if-else construction. There are numerous other ways to do this, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have 6 different functions to establish which period of the day a given date is. It suffices to define a vector which matches the hour with the daytime. For instance:

```
Daytime<-function(rawDate) {
  #change the vector according to your definition of the daytime.
  #the first value corresponds to hour 0 and the last to hour 23
  hours<-c(rep("latenight",5),rep("earlymorning",4),rep("morning",4),rep("afternoon",4),rep("evening",4),rep("earlynight",3))
  hours[as.POSIXlt(as.numeric(rawDate) / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01")$hour+1]
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is what I was looking for - Thank you very much! I did not know about the `rep` function before.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use `cut` rather than `ifelse`. I am not entirely sure how you want to label hours, but this will give you the idea. foo is your data (i.e., calls).

```
library(dplyr)

# Following your idea
ana <- transform(foo, date = as.POSIXlt(as.numeric(date) / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01"))

ana %>%
    mutate(hour = cut(as.numeric(format(date, "%H")),
                      breaks = c(00,04,08,12,16,20,24),
                      label = c("late night", "early morning",
                                "morning", "afternoon",
                                "evening", "early night")
                     )
           )

#  call_id length                date  direction   daytime        hour
#1     258    531 2014-05-20 23:02:52   outgoing afternoon early night
#2     259      0 2013-08-04 03:45:28 unanswered   evening  late night
#3     260    778 2013-12-02 03:30:48   incoming   evening  late night
```

Answer (score 0):

Given Thomas' hint, I solved my problem in the following (addmittedly unelegant) way:

```
Daytime <- function(rawDates) {
  dates <- as.POSIXlt(as.numeric(rawDates) / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01")

  ifelse(is.earlymorning(dates), "earlymorning", 
         ifelse(is.morning(dates), "morning", 
                ifelse(is.afternoon(dates), "afternoon", 
                       ifelse(is.evening(dates), "evening", 
                              ifelse(is.earlynight(dates), "earlynight", 
                                     ifelse(is.latenight(dates), "latenight", 
                                            "N/A")
                                     )
                              )
                       )
                )
         )
}
```

Considering a case with more labels this approach will get unmaintainable soon. Right now it serves my purposes and I will leave it at that since I must focus on analysing the data as soon as possible. But I will let you know if I had time left and found a less complicated solution! Thank you for your quick response, Thomas.